# Rails + SAML + RSpec + Capybara Testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, saml

I have a rails 5 app that uses [omniauth-saml](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth-saml) for authentication. For feature testing with capybara and rspec I currently bypass the saml auth flow but am looking for a better solution that exercises at least some of the saml auth flow without actually hitting our SAML endpoints.

I was thinking perhaps stubbing the methods or perhaps using [webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock).

Has any found a solution they love?

Comment: How did you bypass the saml flow?

Comment: I'm now using OneLogin's Ruby SAML and mocking with `allow(OneLogin::RubySaml::Response).to receive(:new) { saml_response_double(user) }`

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use OneLogin's [SAML Test Connector](https://support.onelogin.com/hc/en-us/articles/202673944-How-to-Use-the-OneLogin-SAML-Test-Connector) to set up a fake SAML IDP.

This would make your tests reliant on network connectivity, but would be a more complete test than stubbing out the method calls.

I think Webmock might be a good solution too, although that would require more setup on your end.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: The above link has no power.